# how to create a UIlabel using a string value in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I have a situation where i have an strings in a NSMutableArray.i want to create UILabel/UITextField or any UI controls by using the string in that array.

For example the array is like this

```
NSMutableArray *myarray=[NSMutableArray initWithObjects:@"label1",@"label2",@"label3",nil];
```

now i will retrieve the object at index position 0 or 1 or 2.Then,i want to use that retrieved string/object to create a UILabel or anything, like this,

```
UILabel *theobjectretrievedfromthearray=[[UILabel alloc]init];
```

**theobjectretrievedfromthearray** means **objects that are taken from the myarray**

How can i do this?Please help me know for implementing this..

Thanks for everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ooooooooopsss
it seems i didn't understand your question:

why don't you use tags for that ? i am guessing that you want to get to those labels later, so just use tags.

by the way if you don't accept answers, and feedback the users for their efforts you are not going to get answers. if you didn't know that it's time to learn.

good day
shani

Comment: +1. Though I will say that instead of tag using dictionary with the texts from the array as the key will be a better solution. As I have already specified in the comment of the question, I don't have enough energy to explain in details what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the strings to be the text on the labels? This is not so hard:

```
UILabel *theobjectretrievedfromarray = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
theobjectretrievedfromarry.text = [myarray objectAtIndex: i];
```

and that's about it. Easy Breasy

Comment: for cgrectmake, x, y, width and height are what you want your label's frame to be. for myarray objectAtIndex: i, i would be the index of the  string in the array that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObjectatIndex`:

`UILabel *requiredobj=[arrayName objectAtIndex:0];`

`requiredobj=[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGReckMake(0,0,13,50)];`

..
..
do not forget to release the labels.